# "Proofs" in logic.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am asked to show the following:

(a) $p \vee q \vee r$, $s \vee \neg q \vee t$ $\vdash p \vee r \vee s \vee t$

(b)$ \varphi(x) \vdash \forall \theta(x)$ if and only if $\exists x \varphi(x) \vdash \theta(x)$

For the first one I can only think of doing the truth table but that seems like a really long way to do it.

For the second one I don't really know what to do since I am not given whether x occurs free or not in the formulas and I don't really know how to come up with these types of proofs.

Comment: So ... you were not given any kind of instructions what type of method to use?

Comment: No. This question is from an old exam and I copied the question as it's stated in the exam.

Comment: Well, assuming you are studying for an upcoming exam, I would say answer the questions using the methods you are supposed to know for that upcoming exam, and if none of them are sufficient to answer these questions ... I would say don't worry about it...

Comment: For the first one, you can use [Resolution rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_rule).

Comment: For the first one, assume for contradiction that some assignment makes the hypotheses true but the RHS false. Then $p,r,s,t$ are all F under that assignment. Then $q$ must be T by the first hypothesis, etc. (I assume its ok to use a semantical argument since you mentioned truth tables).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using a Fitch-style proof checker for the first part:

[image]

Most of this is an exercise in using disjunction introduction and elimination rules. Note that I added parentheses to disambiguate the propositions. This put a constraint on how I would have to construct the proof.

For the second part, various attempts to bind the variables generated countermodels in a [tree proof generator](https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/). Here is an example of one of them:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Tree Proof Generator. https://www.umsu.de/logik/trees/